# apcupsd - BATTERYLEVEL and server reboot

Tags: ups

I have two question regarding apcupsd after a recent power outage

1. shutdown immediately

even though I have configured apcupsd like this:

```
BATTERYLEVEL 7 
MINUTES 4 
TIMEOUT 0
```

It immediately triggered a shutdown upon power loss as taken from the log:

```
2022-09-21 07:23:21 +0200 Power failure. 2022-09-22 09:32:27 +0200 Running on UPS batteries.
2022-09-21 07:24:39 +0200 Battery charge below low limit. 2022-09-22 09:33:39 +0200 Initiating system shutdown!
```

due to low battery. But battery lasts for about 1h. So there is clearly something wrong with the communication between the the UPS and apcupsd. I have a APC UPS Pro 1600s. Does this need any special treatment to work right? should I remove the batterylevel setting and rely on minutes only?

2. reboot server

How can I have a trigger that the server reboots when power is restored? Yes, the motherboard setting for resume is configured but that doesn't really apply in case of a safe shutdown. I mean that is why I have the UPS, to bridge a short outage and prevent disk corruption of a hard shutdown.
So how can I have a safe shutdown but somehow still get a reboot when power is back?

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask APC.

Comment: apcupsd isn't from APC themselves so theoretically they might not even know it exists